# Grabbing selection between specific dates in a DataFrame

Tags: python, datetime, pandas

so I have a large pandas DataFrame that contains about two months of information with a line of info per second. Way too much information to deal with at once, so I want to grab specific timeframes. The following code will grab everything before February 5th 2012:

```
sunflower[sunflower['time'] < '2012-02-05']
```

I want to do the equivalent of this:

```
sunflower['2012-02-01' < sunflower['time'] < '2012-02-05']
```

but that is not allowed. Now I could do this with these two lines:

```
step1 = sunflower[sunflower['time'] < '2012-02-05']
data = step1[step1['time'] > '2012-02-01']
```

but I have to do this with 20 different DataFrames and a multitude of times and being able to do this easily would be nice. I know pandas is capable of this because if my dates were the index rather than a column, it's easy to do, but they can't be the index because dates are repeated and therefore you receive this error:

```
Exception: Reindexing only valid with uniquely valued Index objects
```

So how would I go about doing this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You could define a mask separately:

```
df = DataFrame('a': np.random.randn(100), 'b':np.random.randn(100)})
mask = (df.b > -.5) & (df.b < .5)
df_masked = df[mask]
```

Or in one line:

```
df_masked = df[(df.b > -.5) & (df.b < .5)]
```

Comment: wont that be extremely inefficient if it's a repeated process. I am trying to look at so much data that I would have to type these 3 lines so often. This is why I am looking for a one-liner

Comment: Edited to make a one liner.

Comment: this is actually extremely efficient (whether its a one-liner or not). a mask is just a boolean array. using 2 terms is just anding (or or-ring) with another one, very efficient. and you are only doing this once (the dataframe takes the boolean mask and applies it to the underlying numpy data)

Comment: that one-line is what I was looking for! thanks! and @Jeff: I am not exactly sure how I would only have to do this once. If you read the question I mention that I will have to do this with 20 separate dataframes and look at them at multiple timeframes. Which is why I needed a one-liner so it's not just annoying. A mask is efficient and works great here, I just missed the fact that I could combine it into one line before

Comment: no, what I meant was that the mask is computed only once (per dataframe), and not for each row

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`query`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.query.html) for a more concise option:

```
df.query("'2012-02-01' < time < '2012-02-05'")
```