# Parse a Pandas column to Datetime when importing table from SQL database and filtering rows by date

Tags: python, python-2.7, numpy, scipy, pandas

I have a `DataFrame` with column named `date`. How can we convert/parse the 'date' column to a `DateTime` object?

I loaded the date column from a Postgresql database using `sql.read_frame()`. An example of the `date` column is `2013-04-04`.

What I am trying to do is to select all rows in a dataframe that has their date columns within a certain period, like after `2013-04-01` and before `2013-04-04`.

My attempt below gives the error `'Series' object has no attribute 'read'`

**Attempt**

```
import dateutil

df['date'] = dateutil.parser.parse(df['date'])
```

**Error**

```
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-636-9b19aa5f989c> in <module>()
     15 
     16 # Parse 'Date' Column to Datetime
---> 17 df['date'] = dateutil.parser.parse(df['date'])
     18 
     19 # SELECT RECENT SALES

C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\dateutil\parser.pyc in parse(timestr, parserinfo, **kwargs)
    695         return parser(parserinfo).parse(timestr, **kwargs)
    696     else:
--> 697         return DEFAULTPARSER.parse(timestr, **kwargs)
    698 
    699 

C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\dateutil\parser.pyc in parse(self, timestr, default, ignoretz, tzinfos, **kwargs)
    299             default = datetime.datetime.now().replace(hour=0, minute=0,
    300                                                       second=0, microsecond=0)
--> 301         res = self._parse(timestr, **kwargs)
    302         if res is None:
    303             raise ValueError, "unknown string format"

C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\dateutil\parser.pyc in _parse(self, timestr, dayfirst, yearfirst, fuzzy)
    347             yearfirst = info.yearfirst
    348         res = self._result()
--> 349         l = _timelex.split(timestr)
    350         try:
    351 

C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\dateutil\parser.pyc in split(cls, s)
    141 
    142     def split(cls, s):
--> 143         return list(cls(s))
    144     split = classmethod(split)
    145 

C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\dateutil\parser.pyc in next(self)
    135 
    136     def next(self):
--> 137         token = self.get_token()
    138         if token is None:
    139             raise StopIteration

C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\dateutil\parser.pyc in get_token(self)
     66                 nextchar = self.charstack.pop(0)
     67             else:
---> 68                 nextchar = self.instream.read(1)
     69                 while nextchar == '\x00':
     70                     nextchar = self.instream.read(1)

AttributeError: 'Series' object has no attribute 'read'
```

---

`df['date'].apply(dateutil.parser.parse)` gives me the error `AttributeError: 'datetime.date' object has no attribute 'read'`

`df['date'].truncate(after='2013/04/01')` gives the error `TypeError: can't compare datetime.datetime to long`

`df['date'].dtype` returns `dtype('O')`. Is it already a `datetime` object?

Comment: Please post an example of something in your `date` column! Because pandas should actually recognize a datetime object, so it would be beneficial to see the actual format for that column

Comment: @RyanSaxe I loaded the date column from a Postgresql database using `sql.read_frame()`. An example of the `date` column is `2013-04-04`. How do you check for the dtype of a column?

Comment: `df['date'].dtype` returns `dtype('O')`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

pandas already reads that as a `datetime` object! So what you want is to select rows between two dates and you can do that by masking:

```
df_masked = df[(df.date > '2012-04-01') & (df.date < '2012-04-04')]
```

Because you said that you were getting an error from the string for some reason, try this:

```
df_masked = df[(df.date > datetime.date(2012,4,1)) & (df.date < datetime.date(2012,4,4))]
```

Comment: `df = df[df.date > '2012-01-01']` gives me an error `TypeError: can't compare datetime.date to str`.

Comment: I use this all the time! That's very odd...your question is very similar to one I asked and I was given this answer and it worked. [See it here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16341367/grabbing-selection-between-specific-dates-in-a-dataframe)

Comment: Yes.. it works when I created the dataframe manually... but if I create the dataframe from a SQL database using `sql.read_frame`, `'2012-01-01'` gets treated as a string?

Comment: Trying `df[df.date > dateutil.parser.parse('2013-01-01') ]` gives me `TypeError: can't compare datetime.datetime to datetime.date`

Comment: df.date is type object, but i think `2013-01-01` is treated as a string. The error changes from having a `str` to having a `datetime.date` when I used `dateutil.parser.parse()` *as in above comments*

Comment: I added something, try that!

Answer (score 62):

Pandas is aware of the object datetime but when you use some of the import functions it is taken as a string. So what you need to do is make sure the column is set as the datetime type not as a string. Then you can make your query.

```
df['date']  = pd.to_datetime(df['date'])
df_masked = df[(df['date'] > datetime.date(2012,4,1)) & (df['date'] < datetime.date(2012,4,4))]
```

Answer (score 9):

You probably need `apply`, so something like:

```
df['date'] = df['date'].apply(dateutil.parser.parse)
```

Without an example of the column I can't guarantee this will work, but something in that direction should help you to carry on.

Comment: Thanks, I tried `df['date'].apply(dateutil.parser.parse)` and it gave ethe error. `AttributeError: 'datetime.date' object has no attribute 'read'`. An example of the column is `2013-04-04`. The entire dataframe was loaded from a PostgreSQL database using `sql.readframe()`.

Answer (score 5):

## Don't confuse `datetime.date` with Pandas `pd.Timestamp`

A "Pandas `datetime` series" contains `pd.Timestamp` elements, *not* `datetime.date` elements. The recommended solution for Pandas:

```
s = pd.to_datetime(s)    # convert series to Pandas
mask = s > '2018-03-10'  # calculate Boolean mask against Pandas-compatible object
```

The top answers have issues:

- @RyanSaxe's accepted answer's first attempt doesn't work; the second answer is inefficient.
- As of Pandas v0.23.0, @Keith's highly upvoted answer doesn't work; it gives `TypeError`.

Any good Pandas solution **must** ensure:

1. The series is a Pandas `datetime` series, not `object` dtype.
2. The `datetime` series is compared to a compatible object, e.g. `pd.Timestamp`, or string in the correct format.

Here's a demo with benchmarking, demonstrating that the one-off cost of conversion can be immediately offset by a single operation:

```
from datetime import date

L = [date(2018, 1, 10), date(2018, 5, 20), date(2018, 10, 30), date(2018, 11, 11)]
s = pd.Series(L*10**5)

a = s > date(2018, 3, 10)             # accepted solution #2, inefficient
b = pd.to_datetime(s) > '2018-03-10'  # more efficient, including datetime conversion

assert a.equals(b)                    # check solutions give same result

%timeit s > date(2018, 3, 10)                  # 40.5 ms
%timeit pd.to_datetime(s) > '2018-03-10'       # 33.7 ms

s = pd.to_datetime(s)

%timeit s > '2018-03-10'                       # 2.85 ms
```

Answer (score 2):

You should iterate over the items and parse them independently, then construct a new list.

```
df['date'] = [dateutil.parser.parse(x) for x in df['date']]
```