# Subset of Dataframe based on substring (python)

Tags: python, pandas, substring, dataframe

I have a pandas dataframe called Data filled with dates. An example date might look like:  "2015-05-10 23:45:00". I want to look at the data in January only, so I want:

```
Data= Data[:][5:7]=="01"
```

This doesn't work though.

TDLR, wondering how to find get subset of a dataframe based on a substring.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider using the bracketed filter with datetime's month value. But first, you will need to convert string dates to datetime which can be handled with panda's [to_datetime()](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.to_datetime.html):

```
import datetime as dt
...

Data['yourdatetimecolumn'] = pd.to_datetime(Data['yourdatetimecolumn'])
JanData = Data[Data['yourdatetimecolumn'].dt.month==1]
```

Answer (score 0):

since your query is with regards to Dates, want to start first by looking this up? and give it a try may be..
[Parse a Pandas column to Datetime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16412099/parse-a-pandas-column-to-datetime)