# Filter Pandas DataFrame by time index

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas DataFrame from 6:36 AM to 5:31 PM.  I want to remove all observations where the time is less than 8:00:00 AM.  Here is my attempt:

```
df = df[df.index < '2013-10-16 08:00:00']
```

This does nothing, please help.

Comment: possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16341367/grabbing-selection-between-specific-dates-in-a-dataframe

Comment: that filters by column value, not by timeindex though.  Thanks for the link

Comment: This isn't a duplicate the other post doesn't filter by datetimeindex

Comment: [More generalized solution here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/19179214/2662901).

Answer (score 90, accepted):

You want `df.loc[df.index < '2013-10-16 08:00:00']` since you're selecting by label (index) and not by value.

[selecting by label](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#selection-by-label)

Comment: Oh I had no idea you could use .loc with boolean tests on the index! Great.

Comment: what if it has a multiindex?

Comment: don't have a usecase handy, but I'd suspect it's: `df.loc[(df.index['a'] < something & df.index['b'] < another_thing)]`

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`query`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.query.html) for a more concise option:

```
df.query("index < '2013-10-16 08:00:00'")
```