# ValueError: index must be monotonic increasing or decreasing, including index,column, ffill at the same time

Tags: python, dataframe, valueerror

the pandas version I use is '0.20.1', python 3

Though there are two questions:
[question1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42510412/valueerror-index-must-be-monotonic-increasing-or-decreasing-adding-millisecon) , [question2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31285508/valueerror-index-must-be-monotonic-increasing-or-decreasing)
 have been asked with same error, while I found those two questions are not the same situation with me.

The data is source from the book "Python for data analysis", page 123-124.
when I run the following codes,

```
frame = DataFrame(np.arange(9).reshape((3, 3)), index=['a', 'c', 'd'],
                  columns=['Ohio', 'Texas', 'California'])
states = ['Texas', 'Utah', 'California']
frame.reindex(index=['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'], method='ffill',columns=states)
```

it report error

```
ValueError: index must be monotonic increasing or decreasing
```

while I have tried following two expression, they run successfully:

```
frame.reindex(index=['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'], columns=states)
```

or

```
frame.reindex(index=['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'], method='ffill')
```

***********************update***************

I tried this code,

```
frame3=frame.reindex(index=['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'], method='ffill').reindex(columns=states)
```

then it return the same result as the book.

```
Out[92]:
Texas Utah California
a 1 NaN 2
b 1 NaN 2
c 4 NaN 5
d 7 NaN 8
```

Comment: What version of pandas are you using? Your exact code works for me on  0.18.1

Comment: pandas version is '0.20.1', python 3

Comment: @ DeepSpace, do you mean "frame3=frame.reindex(index=['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'], method='ffill').reindex(columns=states)" works for you ?

Comment: Yes, it does...

Comment: thanks, maybe previous pandas version can run the code as the book.  if someone use previous version of pandas, please let me know, thanks.

Answer (score -1):

Because the columns are also reindexed, which are not monotonic increasing or decreasing.

Comment: Consider adding more details/context to help the OP

Comment: If you change the code to
*frame.reindex(index=[1,2,3,4],method='ffill', columns=[1,2,3])*
it doesn't work either - pandas 0.25.1 and Python 3.7.3