# How to search date in data frame?

Tags: python, pandas

I have to search a date in the data frame.  rpi_index_start_date is storing value '1/1/2012' which is a string.

The data frame where i have to search values is in below format. After searching the date(1/1/2012) in the dataframe i have to get corresponding RPI amount.

```
Start Date  End Date    RPI Amount
1/1/1987    31/01/1987  100.0
2/1/1987    28/02/1987  100.4
3/1/1987    31/03/1987  100.6
4/1/1987    30/04/1987  101.8
5/1/1987    31/05/1987  101.9
6/1/1987    30/06/1987  101.9
7/1/1987    31/07/1987  101.8
8/1/1987    31/08/1987  102.1
9/1/1987    30/09/1987  102.4
10/1/1987   31/10/1987  102.9
11/1/1987   30/11/1987  103.4
12/1/1987   31/12/1987  103.3
1/1/1988    31/01/1988  103.3
2/1/1988    29/02/1988  103.7
3/1/1988    31/03/1988  104.1
4/1/1988    30/04/1988  105.8
5/1/1988    31/05/1988  106.2
6/1/1988    30/06/1988  106.6
7/1/1988    31/07/1988  106.7
8/1/1988    31/08/1988  107.9
9/1/1988    30/09/1988  108.4
10/1/1988   31/10/1988  109.5
11/1/1988   30/11/1988  110.0
12/1/1988   31/12/1988  110.3
1/1/1989    31/01/1989  111.0
2/1/1989    28/02/1989  111.8
3/1/1989    31/03/1989  112.3
4/1/1989    30/04/1989  114.3
5/1/1989    31/05/1989  115.0
6/1/1989    30/06/1989  115.4
7/1/1989    31/07/1989  115.5
8/1/1989    31/08/1989  115.8
9/1/1989    30/09/1989  116.6
10/1/1989   31/10/1989  117.5
11/1/1989   30/11/1989  118.5
12/1/1989   31/12/1989  118.8
1/1/1990    31/01/1990  119.5
2/1/1990    28/02/1990  120.2
3/1/1990    31/03/1990  121.4
4/1/1990    30/04/1990  125.1
5/1/1990    31/05/1990  126.2
6/1/1990    30/06/1990  126.7
7/1/1990    31/07/1990  126.8
8/1/1990    31/08/1990  128.1
9/1/1990    30/09/1990  129.3
10/1/1990   31/10/1990  130.3
11/1/1990   30/11/1990  130.0
12/1/1990   31/12/1990  129.9
1/1/1991    31/01/1991  130.2
2/1/1991    28/02/1991  130.9
3/1/1991    31/03/1991  131.4
4/1/1991    30/04/1991  133.1
5/1/1991    31/05/1991  133.5
6/1/1991    30/06/1991  134.1
7/1/1991    31/07/1991  133.8
8/1/1991    31/08/1991  134.1
9/1/1991    30/09/1991  134.6
10/1/1991   31/10/1991  135.1
11/1/1991   30/11/1991  135.6
12/1/1991   31/12/1991  135.7
1/1/1992    31/01/1992  135.6
2/1/1992    29/02/1992  136.3
3/1/1992    31/03/1992  136.7
4/1/1992    30/04/1992  138.8
5/1/1992    31/05/1992  139.3
6/1/1992    30/06/1992  139.3
7/1/1992    31/07/1992  138.8
8/1/1992    31/08/1992  138.9
9/1/1992    30/09/1992  139.4
10/1/1992   31/10/1992  139.9
11/1/1992   30/11/1992  139.7
12/1/1992   31/12/1992  139.2
1/1/1993    31/01/1993  137.9
2/1/1993    28/02/1993  138.8
3/1/1993    31/03/1993  139.3
4/1/1993    30/04/1993  140.6
5/1/1993    31/05/1993  141.1
6/1/1993    30/06/1993  141.0
7/1/1993    31/07/1993  140.7
8/1/1993    31/08/1993  141.3
9/1/1993    30/09/1993  141.9
10/1/1993   31/10/1993  141.8
11/1/1993   30/11/1993  141.6
12/1/1993   31/12/1993  141.9
1/1/1994    31/01/1994  141.3
2/1/1994    28/02/1994  142.1
3/1/1994    31/03/1994  142.5
4/1/1994    30/04/1994  144.2
5/1/1994    31/05/1994  144.7
6/1/1994    30/06/1994  144.7
7/1/1994    31/07/1994  144.0
8/1/1994    31/08/1994  144.7
9/1/1994    30/09/1994  145.0
10/1/1994   31/10/1994  145.2
11/1/1994   30/11/1994  145.3
12/1/1994   31/12/1994  146.0
1/1/1995    31/01/1995  146.0
2/1/1995    28/02/1995  146.9
3/1/1995    31/03/1995  147.5
4/1/1995    30/04/1995  149.0
5/1/1995    31/05/1995  149.6
6/1/1995    30/06/1995  149.8
7/1/1995    31/07/1995  149.1
8/1/1995    31/08/1995  149.9
9/1/1995    30/09/1995  150.6
10/1/1995   31/10/1995  149.8
11/1/1995   30/11/1995  149.8
12/1/1995   31/12/1995  150.7
1/1/1996    31/01/1996  150.2
2/1/1996    29/02/1996  150.9
3/1/1996    31/03/1996  151.5
4/1/1996    30/04/1996  152.6
5/1/1996    31/05/1996  152.9
6/1/1996    30/06/1996  153.0
7/1/1996    31/07/1996  152.4
8/1/1996    31/08/1996  153.1
9/1/1996    30/09/1996  153.8
10/1/1996   31/10/1996  153.8
11/1/1996   30/11/1996  153.9
12/1/1996   31/12/1996  154.4
1/1/1997    31/01/1997  154.4
2/1/1997    28/02/1997  155.0
3/1/1997    31/03/1997  155.4
4/1/1997    30/04/1997  156.3
5/1/1997    31/05/1997  156.9
6/1/1997    30/06/1997  157.5
7/1/1997    31/07/1997  157.5
8/1/1997    31/08/1997  158.5
9/1/1997    30/09/1997  159.3
10/1/1997   31/10/1997  159.5
11/1/1997   30/11/1997  159.6
12/1/1997   31/12/1997  160.0
1/1/1998    31/01/1998  159.5
2/1/1998    28/02/1998  160.3
3/1/1998    31/03/1998  160.8
4/1/1998    30/04/1998  162.6
5/1/1998    31/05/1998  163.5
6/1/1998    30/06/1998  163.4
7/1/1998    31/07/1998  163.0
8/1/1998    31/08/1998  163.7
9/1/1998    30/09/1998  164.4
10/1/1998   31/10/1998  164.5
11/1/1998   30/11/1998  164.4
12/1/1998   31/12/1998  164.4
1/1/1999    31/01/1999  163.4
2/1/1999    28/02/1999  163.7
3/1/1999    31/03/1999  164.1
4/1/1999    30/04/1999  165.2
5/1/1999    31/05/1999  165.6
6/1/1999    30/06/1999  165.6
7/1/1999    31/07/1999  165.1
8/1/1999    31/08/1999  165.5
9/1/1999    30/09/1999  166.2
10/1/1999   31/10/1999  166.5
11/1/1999   30/11/1999  166.7
12/1/1999   31/12/1999  167.3
1/1/2000    31/01/2000  166.6
2/1/2000    29/02/2000  167.5
3/1/2000    31/03/2000  168.4
4/1/2000    30/04/2000  170.1
5/1/2000    31/05/2000  170.7
6/1/2000    30/06/2000  171.1
7/1/2000    31/07/2000  170.5
8/1/2000    31/08/2000  170.5
9/1/2000    30/09/2000  171.7
10/1/2000   31/10/2000  171.6
11/1/2000   30/11/2000  172.1
12/1/2000   31/12/2000  172.2
1/1/2001    31/01/2001  171.1
2/1/2001    28/02/2001  172.0
3/1/2001    31/03/2001  172.2
4/1/2001    30/04/2001  173.1
5/1/2001    31/05/2001  174.2
6/1/2001    30/06/2001  174.4
7/1/2001    31/07/2001  173.3
8/1/2001    31/08/2001  174.0
9/1/2001    30/09/2001  174.6
10/1/2001   31/10/2001  174.3
11/1/2001   30/11/2001  173.6
12/1/2001   31/12/2001  173.4
1/1/2002    31/01/2002  173.3
2/1/2002    28/02/2002  173.8
3/1/2002    31/03/2002  174.5
4/1/2002    30/04/2002  175.7
5/1/2002    31/05/2002  176.2
6/1/2002    30/06/2002  176.2
7/1/2002    31/07/2002  175.9
8/1/2002    31/08/2002  176.4
9/1/2002    30/09/2002  177.6
10/1/2002   31/10/2002  177.9
11/1/2002   30/11/2002  178.2
12/1/2002   31/12/2002  178.5
1/1/2003    31/01/2003  178.4
2/1/2003    28/02/2003  179.3
3/1/2003    31/03/2003  179.9
4/1/2003    30/04/2003  181.2
5/1/2003    31/05/2003  181.5
6/1/2003    30/06/2003  181.3
7/1/2003    31/07/2003  181.3
8/1/2003    31/08/2003  181.6
9/1/2003    30/09/2003  182.5
10/1/2003   31/10/2003  182.6
11/1/2003   30/11/2003  182.7
12/1/2003   31/12/2003  183.5
1/1/2004    31/01/2004  183.1
2/1/2004    29/02/2004  183.8
3/1/2004    31/03/2004  184.6
4/1/2004    30/04/2004  185.7
5/1/2004    31/05/2004  186.5
6/1/2004    30/06/2004  186.8
7/1/2004    31/07/2004  186.8
8/1/2004    31/08/2004  187.4
9/1/2004    30/09/2004  188.1
10/1/2004   31/10/2004  188.6
11/1/2004   30/11/2004  189.0
12/1/2004   31/12/2004  189.9
1/1/2005    31/01/2005  188.9
2/1/2005    28/02/2005  189.6
3/1/2005    31/03/2005  190.5
4/1/2005    30/04/2005  191.6
5/1/2005    31/05/2005  192.0
6/1/2005    30/06/2005  192.2
7/1/2005    31/07/2005  192.2
8/1/2005    31/08/2005  192.6
9/1/2005    30/09/2005  193.1
10/1/2005   31/10/2005  193.3
11/1/2005   30/11/2005  193.6
12/1/2005   31/12/2005  194.1
1/1/2006    31/01/2006  193.4
2/1/2006    28/02/2006  194.2
3/1/2006    31/03/2006  195.0
4/1/2006    30/04/2006  196.5
5/1/2006    31/05/2006  197.7
6/1/2006    30/06/2006  198.5
7/1/2006    31/07/2006  198.5
8/1/2006    31/08/2006  199.2
9/1/2006    30/09/2006  200.1
10/1/2006   31/10/2006  200.4
11/1/2006   30/11/2006  201.1
12/1/2006   31/12/2006  202.7
1/1/2007    31/01/2007  201.6
2/1/2007    28/02/2007  203.1
3/1/2007    31/03/2007  204.4
4/1/2007    30/04/2007  205.4
5/1/2007    31/05/2007  206.2
6/1/2007    30/06/2007  207.3
7/1/2007    31/07/2007  206.1
8/1/2007    31/08/2007  207.3
9/1/2007    30/09/2007  208.0
10/1/2007   31/10/2007  208.9
11/1/2007   30/11/2007  209.7
12/1/2007   31/12/2007  210.9
1/1/2008    31/01/2008  209.8
2/1/2008    29/02/2008  211.4
3/1/2008    31/03/2008  212.1
4/1/2008    30/04/2008  214.0
5/1/2008    31/05/2008  215.1
6/1/2008    30/06/2008  216.8
7/1/2008    31/07/2008  216.5
8/1/2008    31/08/2008  217.2
9/1/2008    30/09/2008  218.4
10/1/2008   31/10/2008  217.7
11/1/2008   30/11/2008  216.0
12/1/2008   31/12/2008  212.9
1/1/2009    31/01/2009  210.1
2/1/2009    28/02/2009  211.4
3/1/2009    31/03/2009  211.3
4/1/2009    30/04/2009  211.5
5/1/2009    31/05/2009  212.8
6/1/2009    30/06/2009  213.4
7/1/2009    31/07/2009  213.4
8/1/2009    31/08/2009  214.4
9/1/2009    30/09/2009  215.3
10/1/2009   31/10/2009  216.0
11/1/2009   30/11/2009  216.6
12/1/2009   31/12/2009  218.0
1/1/2010    31/01/2010  217.9
2/1/2010    28/02/2010  219.2
3/1/2010    31/03/2010  220.7
4/1/2010    30/04/2010  222.8
5/1/2010    31/05/2010  223.6
6/1/2010    30/06/2010  224.1
7/1/2010    31/07/2010  223.6
8/1/2010    31/08/2010  224.5
9/1/2010    30/09/2010  225.3
10/1/2010   31/10/2010  225.8
11/1/2010   30/11/2010  226.8
12/1/2010   31/12/2010  228.4
1/1/2011    31/01/2011  229.0
2/1/2011    28/02/2011  231.3
3/1/2011    31/03/2011  232.5
4/1/2011    30/04/2011  234.4
5/1/2011    31/05/2011  235.2
    31/12/1899  235.2
7/1/2011    31/07/2011  234.7
8/1/2011    31/08/2011  236.1
9/1/2011    30/09/2011  237.9
10/1/2011   31/10/2011  238.0
11/1/2011   30/11/2011  238.5
12/1/2011   31/12/2011  239.4
1/1/2012    31/01/2012  238.0
2/1/2012    29/02/2012  239.9
3/1/2012    31/03/2012  240.8
4/1/2012    30/04/2012  242.5
5/1/2012    31/05/2012  242.4
6/1/2012    30/06/2012  241.8
7/1/2012    31/07/2012  242.1
8/1/2012    31/08/2012  243.0
9/1/2012    30/09/2012  244.2
10/1/2012   31/10/2012  245.6
11/1/2012   30/11/2012  245.6
12/1/2012   31/12/2012  246.8
1/1/2013    31/01/2013  245.8
2/1/2013    28/02/2013  247.6
3/1/2013    31/03/2013  248.7
4/1/2013    30/04/2013  249.5
5/1/2013    31/05/2013  250.0
6/1/2013    30/06/2013  249.7
7/1/2013    31/07/2013  249.7
8/1/2013    31/08/2013  251.0
9/1/2013    30/09/2013  251.9
10/1/2013   31/10/2013  251.9
11/1/2013   30/11/2013  252.1
12/1/2013   31/12/2013  253.4
1/1/2014    31/01/2014  252.6
2/1/2014    28/02/2014  254.2
3/1/2014    31/03/2014  254.8
4/1/2014    30/04/2014  255.7
5/1/2014    31/05/2014  255.9
6/1/2014    30/06/2014  256.3
7/1/2014    31/07/2014  256.0
8/1/2014    31/08/2014  257.0
9/1/2014    30/09/2014  257.6
10/1/2014   31/10/2014  257.7
11/1/2014   30/11/2014  257.1
12/1/2014   31/12/2014  257.5
1/1/2015    31/01/2015  255.4
2/1/2015    28/02/2015  256.7
3/1/2015    31/03/2015  257.1
4/1/2015    30/04/2015  258.0
5/1/2015    31/05/2015  258.5
6/1/2015    30/06/2015  258.9
7/1/2015    31/07/2015  258.6
8/1/2015    31/08/2015  259.8
9/1/2015    30/09/2015  259.6
10/1/2015   31/10/2015  259.5
11/1/2015   30/11/2015  259.8
12/1/2015   31/12/2015  260.6
1/1/2016    31/01/2016  258.8
2/1/2016    29/02/2016  260.0
3/1/2016    31/03/2016  261.1
4/1/2016    30/04/2016  261.4
5/1/2016    31/05/2016  262.1
6/1/2016    30/06/2016  263.1
7/1/2016    31/07/2016  263.4
8/1/2016    31/08/2016  264.4
9/1/2016    30/09/2016  264.9
10/1/2016   31/10/2016  264.8
11/1/2016   30/11/2016  265.5
12/1/2016   31/12/2016  267.1
1/1/2017    31/01/2017  265.5
2/1/2017    28/02/2017  268.4
3/1/2017    31/03/2017  269.3
4/1/2017    30/04/2017  270.6
5/1/2017    31/05/2017  271.7
6/1/2017    30/06/2017  272.3
7/1/2017    31/07/2017  272.9
8/1/2017    31/08/2017  274.7
9/1/2017    30/09/2017  275.1
10/1/2017   31/10/2017  275.3
11/1/2017   30/11/2017  275.8
12/1/2017   31/12/2017  278.1
1/1/2018    31/01/2018  276.0
2/1/2018    28/02/2018  278.1
3/1/2018    31/03/2018  278.3
```

By using for loop i tried to iterate over dataframe and then match the rpi_index_start_date(which stores "1/1/2012") with dataframe date. However the format does not matches.

```
rpi_index_start_date=rpi_index_start_date.strftime("%d/%m/%Y")

for i,row in rpi_rates_df.iterrows():
    if rpi_index_start_date==str(rpi_rates_df.loc[i,"Start Date"]):
        index_start_rpi=rpi_rates_df.loc[i,"RPI Amount"]
    else:
        index_start_rpi="NA"
```

My output should be 238 however i am getting output as "NA"

Comment: In general you should create a **minimal** reproducible example: [mcve]. This problem could be illustrated with 4-5 rows at most; that amount of data just distracts.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Filtering Pandas DataFrames on dates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22898824/filtering-pandas-dataframes-on-dates)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand your question and the dataframe correctly, shouldnt it just be this:

```
df.loc[df['Start Date'] == '1/1/2012']['RPI Amount']
```

Output:

```
df.loc[df['Start Date'] == '1/1/2012']['RPI Amount']
Out[58]: 
0    238.0
Name: RPI Amount, dtype: float64
```

---

Since you are not doing any kind of comparison like `> 1/1/2012` or `< 1/1/2012`, I doubt you even require to convert it to datetime format. Will edit the answer, if that is required.

Comment: rpi_index_start_date=datetime.strptime(f"{temp_month}/1/{temp_year}","%m/%d/%Y")

for i,row in rpi_rates_df.iterrows():
    if rpi_index_start_date==rpi_rates_df.loc[i,"Start Date"]:
        index_start_dateee_rpi=rpi_rates_df.l\oc[i,"RPI Amount"]


--------------------------------------------------------------------------------

index_start_dateee_rpi
Out[30]: 238.0

Answer (score 0):

Your code works fine. But strftime format string is not suitable for your case.

**TL;DR:** Place **#** (Windows) or **-** (UNIX) before day and month formats. "%#d/%#m/%Y" or "%-d/%-m/%Y"

If you create datetime object somehow like this:

```
rpi_index_start_date = datetime(2012, 1, 1).strftime("%d/%m/%Y")
```

you end up with leading zeroes.

```
In: print(str.encode(rpi_index_start_date))
Out: b'01/01/2012'
```