# How to use .loc to filter based on date fields

Tags: python, pandas, jupyter

Recently I started playing around with Python and have been stuck with an issue related to Pandas (particularly .loc) for a while now. Basically, I am just trying to manipulate the dataframe so that it only keeps certain date ranges.

When I filter for one specific date the command runs flawlessly but as soon as I switch for a range it won't. Also, any other variable type works fine - I'm surprised because people must have to filter for dates all the time. Do I have to transform the date?

```
# this works perfectly fine
raw_data.loc[raw_data['date_field'] == '2019-06-20', 'id':'date_field']

# this does not
raw_data.loc[raw_data['date_field'] >= '2019-06-20', 'id':'date_field']
```

I get a type error:

TypeError Traceback (most recent call last)

Now, I have tried all sorts of different transformations of the date field but keep getting the same error. Is it at all possible to filter dates using .loc?

Comment: Check out this answer : https://stackoverflow.com/a/50901506/2570277

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think here is necessary convert column to datetimes by [`to_datetime`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.to_datetime.html):

```
raw_data['date_field'] = pd.to_datetime(raw_data['date_field'])
raw_data.loc[raw_data['date_field'] >= '2019-06-20', 'id':'date_field']
```