# Pandas Filter date

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe like the following,

```
+-----------+-------+----------+--+--+
| Date      | OPP   | Result   |  |  |
+-----------+-------+----------+--+--+
| Sat 11/16 | @DAL  | L110-102 |  |  |
+-----------+-------+----------+--+--+
| Wed 11/13 | @POR  | W114-106 |  |  |
+-----------+-------+----------+--+--+
| Mon 11/11 | @LAC  | L98-88   |  |  |
+-----------+-------+----------+--+--+
| Sun 11/10 | @LAL  | W113-104 |  |  |
+-----------+-------+----------+--+--+
| Fri 11/8  | @NO   | W122-104 |  |  |
+-----------+-------+----------+--+--+
| Wed 11/6  | vsSAC | W124-120 |  |  |
+-----------+-------+----------+--+--+
| Sat 11/2  | @MIL  | L115-105 |  |  |
+-----------+-------+----------+--+--+
```

I am trying to filter for dates > _____ .

Ie here is what I have tried, but does not filter all the date greater then Sun 11/10

`d1 = d1[(d1['Date'] > 'Sun 11/10')]`

**Update**

My column now looks like this, I need to be able to filter New_Date > _____ and exclude "NaT".   Trying `d1[(d1['New_Date'] > '2019-11-01')]` but not working.

```
0    2019-11-20
1    2019-11-18
2    2019-11-16
3    2019-11-13
4    2019-11-11
5    2019-11-10
6    2019-11-08
7    2019-11-06
8    2019-11-02
9    2019-11-01
10   2019-10-30
11   2019-10-28
12   2019-10-26
13   2019-10-01
14          NaT
15          NaT
16   2019-10-18
17   2019-10-13
18   2019-10-10
19   2019-10-08
20          NaT
21          NaT
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: try convert to datetime first

Comment: Please dont post your dataframe as images. Post as dictionary so its easy for others to copy and test. You can do `df.to_dict` to get dictionary of data frame.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Filtering Pandas DataFrames on dates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22898824/filtering-pandas-dataframes-on-dates)

Comment: slightly different based on the date format. Will  need to convert the dates somehow.

Comment: You can parse dates using pandas `to_datetime` or the datetime library. This website http://strftime.org should be helpful in figuring out which format tot use

Comment: With my answer you could change the boolean to :  newdf[(newdf['Date'] > '2019-11-10') & (newdf['Date'] != 'NaT')]    If you want i come up with a solution that drops those before the search. Or create an apply map the calls a search function to drop them

Answer (score 1):

First you need to convert your date into proper `datetime` object, providing proper input format (which I assumed is `<weekday> <month>/<day>` - you can tweak it as per `datetime` documentation: https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-behavior ). You can do it in a following way:

```py
df["Date_2"]=pd.to_datetime(df["Date"].astype(str), format="%a %m/%d")
```

Then use analogical transformation on the filter criteria using python `datetime.strptime()` method:

```py
from datetime import datetime

df.loc[df["Date_2"]>datetime.strptime("Thu 11/12", "%a %m/%d")]
```

So the whole example:

```py
import pandas as pd
from datetime import datetime

df=pd.DataFrame({"Date": ["Sat 11/16", "Fri 11/8", "Wed 11/13"], "x": [4,3,7]})


df["Date_2"]=pd.to_datetime(df["Date"].astype(str), format="%a %m/%d")
print("\nExample filtered: ")
print(df.loc[df["Date_2"]>datetime.strptime("Thu 11/12", "%a %m/%d")])
print("\nThe whole thing:")
print(df)
```

And output:

```py
Example filtered:
        Date  x     Date_2
0  Sat 11/16  4 1900-11-16
2  Wed 11/13  7 1900-11-13

The whole thing:
        Date  x     Date_2
0  Sat 11/16  4 1900-11-16
1   Fri 11/8  3 1900-11-08
2  Wed 11/13  7 1900-11-13
```

(Since no year is provided it's assumed to be `1900`)

Comment: hi , ive updated my question, i was able to convert my date to a yyyy-mm-dd format, now need to filter for > then _____ .

Answer (score 1):

Are you open to changing the format to another, or having a separate column with  a date that is searchable by your critieria? I wrote this solution showing that route, maybe it will help you with ideas, and i'm open to suggestions for changes:

```
newdf = pd.read_csv('testdata2.csv', parse_dates=["Date"], date_parser=lambda x: pd.to_datetime(x, format="%a %m/%d"), 
index_col="Date") 

newdf = newdf.reset_index()   
newdf['Date'] = newdf['Date'].mask(newdf['Date'].dt.year == 1900, newdf['Date'] + pd.offsets.DateOffset(year=2019))

newdf[(newdf['Date'] > '2019-11/10')]
#Out[63]: 
#        Date   OPP    Result
#0 2019-11-16  @DAL  L110-102
#1 2019-11-13  @POR  W114-106
#2 2019-11-11  @LAC    L98-88
```

Answer (score 0):

From what I understand, are you trying to filter dates just to remove **NaTs**? Then that's not how you do it. Infact, Pandas have several functions that can check for NaTs e.g. pandas.isnull(), pandas.notna(), pandas.DataFrame.notna(), etc. :

Here's a quick example as how to use it

```
    >>> import pandas as pd
    >>> pd.isnull(np.datetime64('NaT'))
    True
    >>> d1[d1['New_Date'].notna()]
```