# Select rows based on date in a Pandas' Dataframe in Python (date is not a column)

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have got a dataframe like:

```
*nothing*            open          high
2020-01-12            122            59
2020-01-13            113            52
2020-02-14            144            64
2020-03-15            135            64
```

How can I only select rows from 2020-01-13 to 2020-02-14 using a filter? I'm aware there are more questions like these but this dataframe doesn't have a name for the date column (e.g. the date is the index).

Thank you!

Comment: I'm using Python and Pandas' module.

Comment: did you try [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22898824/filtering-pandas-dataframes-on-dates) ?

Comment: `df.loc['2020-01-13':'2020-02-14']`

Comment: Thanks for the quick help, it works as expected now!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can filter the index using `loc`:

```
df.loc[(df.index >= '2020-01-13') & (df.index <= '2020-02-14')]
```