# How to filter time with respect to date in pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, filtering

I have this data in mysql and i have read it into pandas using read_sql. Data:

```
    count    InTime         Day
0       1  19:10:14  2021-02-28
1       2  19:10:26  2021-02-28
2       3  19:10:47  2021-02-28
3       4  19:10:47  2021-02-28
4       1  20:06:53  2021-02-28
5       2  20:07:03  2021-02-28
6       3  20:07:23  2021-02-28
7       4  20:07:23  2021-02-28
8       1  10:32:57  2021-03-01
9       2  10:33:08  2021-03-01
10      3  10:33:28  2021-03-01
11      4  10:33:28  2021-03-01
```

I have converted the columns to the required datetime format. Now i would like to find the count on 28th between 19:00:00 and 20:00:00. How do i do this ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Filtering Pandas DataFrames on dates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22898824/filtering-pandas-dataframes-on-dates)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create datetimes anf filter by [`Series.between`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.between.html) in [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing):

```
df['datetime'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Day'] + ' ' + df['InTime'])

df1 = df[df['datetime'].between('2021-02-28 19:00:00', '2021-02-28 20:00:00')]
print (df1)
   count    InTime         Day            datetime
0      1  19:10:14  2021-02-28 2021-02-28 19:10:14
1      2  19:10:26  2021-02-28 2021-02-28 19:10:26
2      3  19:10:47  2021-02-28 2021-02-28 19:10:47
3      4  19:10:47  2021-02-28 2021-02-28 19:10:47
```

If need filter only `count` column use [`DataFrame.loc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html):

```
s = df.loc[df['datetime'].between('2021-02-28 19:00:00', '2021-02-28 20:00:00'), 'count']
print (s)
0    1
1    2
2    3
3    4
Name: count, dtype: int64
```