# How to extract total year rows and columns from multiindex to create histograms in plotly

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, plotly

How do I create dataframes showing daily data for each year to create histograms in plotly?

```
                                Open        High        Low         Close       Volume      
   Date                         
   2019-06-26                  81.478964    81.789175   80.102395   80.422302   5731400  
   2019-06-27                  80.839148    81.411104   80.528937   81.129974   4111600 
   2019-06-28                  81.255994    81.682537   80.577409   81.527428   16436700
   .....
   2020-12-31                  81.255994    81.682537   80.577409   81.527428   16436700
```

I want my output for 2019 data frame to have all of 2019 transactions and my other dataframe to have all of 2020 transactions

Comment: Have a look at this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/61339028/3376059
The last suggested option there will allow you to filter by year, I hope this is what you were asking (so if not, more elaboration could do).
Also, please provide a way to re-create the dataframe.

Comment: Can you be a little more specific, which values of OHLC do you want to graph? Do you have an example of the output you expect?

Comment: @OmerM25 That is exactly what I wanted. Do I delete my question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try with

```
d = {x : y for x , y in df.groupby(df.index.year)}
```

Answer (score 0):

As you have datetime index, you can use [`DatetimeIndex.year`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DatetimeIndex.year.html) to get the year of index to filter the year, like below:

```
df_2019 = df.loc[df.index.year == 2019]
df_2020 = df.loc[df.index.year == 2020]
```

You can also use:

```
df_2019 = df.loc['2019-01-01':'2019-12-31']
df_2020 = df.loc['2020-01-01':'2020-12-31']
```